# Will adding large static data file to small git repo affect performance in future?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on a small git repo, in the 5-10 mb range, hosted privately in GitLab. While small, this repo is important and updated several times a week. There's a static data file that would be useful to add, it's ~100mb, JSON, and will almost certainly never change. Without it, I'll have to make frequent requests to an outside API, which will cost some money and mean longer execution time.

Will committing that data file to the git repo cause issues/headaches down the line in git in performance or storage? My understanding is that new branches only record changes to files, and so the data file wouldn't be duplicated for new branches, only for cloning.

Comment: Yes, what you say might be correct, but in any case why can't you use bucket storage such as S3 on AWS, or something similar?  It would probably be a lot cheaper, and more appropriate as a long term file store.

Comment: You're fine. Every commit is a full snapshot but git's dedup will handle your case trivally.

Comment: 100MB JSON probably compresses pretty well and will only require ~10MB in your .git folder. You can try locally to see how much it will blow up your repo size. As long as the file really does not change often, you should be fine (but clones will take longer)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single static file, which compresses well, then it probably won't matter much. To find out how well your JSON file compresses, you can create a throwaway Git repository to gauge the compressed size:

```
git init
cp path/to/your-file.json .
git add your-file.json
git commit -m 'big json test'
git gc
du -sh .git # probably in the ballpark of ~10M
```

Just don't add big binary files (use [Git LFS (Large File Storage)](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for that) and don't edit the file too often.